# Difference filter_input_array and filter_input with filter_require_array

Tags: php

I wonder something. I need to use filter_input and previously I've only used `filter_input` with `filter_require_array` set. But now I've seen a function called `filter_require_array`. Is there any difference and what is the difference? For example, I've got this html:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="test[]">
    <input type="text" name="test[]">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

And this PHP (this is just an example, so this isn't the best code):

```
<?php

$test = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'test', FILTER_DEFAULT, FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY);
$test2 = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, 'test');

echo '<pre>';
echo var_dump($test);
echo '</pre>';
echo '<hr>';
echo '<pre>';
echo var_dump($test2);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

The code gives on the `var_dump($test)` the following result:

```
array(2) {
    [0]=>
        string(5) "test1"
    [1]=>
        string(5) "test2"
}
```

Now, at the `var_dump($test2)`, it gives the following result:

```
bool(false)
```

Why does `filter_input_array` return a false in this case? If I could use filter_require_array, I'd use it since I think it's better, but I'm not sure.

Comment: [Read the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input-array.php) and look at the examples!

Comment: I know... I really tried reading it but I just simply doesn't understand it. That's why I asked it here because sometimes people here explain it better for me.

Comment: The docs are really quite clear. What exactly do you not understand?

Comment: Well because in my example I'm using `INPUT_POST`, I send `test[]` and it's an array. So I don't understand why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

You are using `filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, 'test');`,

**Watch out for the second argument**!

- the second argument for `filter_input()` is the `$variable_name`
- while, the second argument of `filter_input_array()` is **not** the variable_name, but the filter definition, e.g. `filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, $filter_definition);`

  Where a `$filter_definition` could be:

  ```
  $filter_definition = [
      'test' => ['filter' => FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, 
                 'flags'  => FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY],
  ];
  ```

Quoting the PHP manual for [filter_input_array](http://php.net/manual/de/function.filter-input-array.php) :

`mixed filter_input_array ( int $type [, mixed $definition [, bool $add_empty = true ]] )`